# How to make usernames banned on a website

Tags: javascript, html

How can I find out if a text input is a certain text?

I tried this

```
<script>
    var b = document.getElementById('button')
    var u = document.getElementById('username')
    var p = document.getElementById('password')
    
    var bannedUsers = ["user1012"];
    
    b.onclick = function() {
      if(u.value.length <= 20 && p.value.length >= 6 && u.value.length >= 3 && !u.value === bannedUsers) {
        location.href = "";
    };
      
      if(u.value.length > 20) {
        return alert('Username needs to be below 20 characters.')
      } else if(u.value.length < 3) {
        return alert('Username needs to be above 2 characters')
      }
      
      if(p.value.length < 6) {
        return alert('Password needs to be over 6 characters.')
      }
      
      if(u.value === bannedUsers) {
        return alert('That username is banned.')
      }
    }
    </script>
```

But it ended up just taking me to the page instead of saying "This username is banned"

Comment: do it server-side and make an ajax call, around the same time as you validate the above and check for an existing user with the same username

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, make sure legit words aren't banned! Some words have bad words within them, so please don't block those!

Comment: It does not really make sense to be returning an alert call `alert('xxxx'); return false;` It will work, just does not the best thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `includes` method.

```
bannedUsers.includes(u.value)
```

what you're doing right now is checking if the string is the array bannedUsers, translating to this: `'user1012' === '[object Object]'`

Comment: Yes i have tried that before that's what i tried the first time

Comment: @Yoimolk Then you should edit your post to use .includes, so we can figure out what's wrong. Using `.includes` is "more right".

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Array.prototype.includes method to test if a given value is in an array. includes will return a boolean true or false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```js
if (bannedUsers.includes(u.value) {
  return alert('That username is banned.')
}
```